# Laravel passport / allow api routes for guests / bypass Laravel api middleware

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport, laravel-middleware, laravel-api

This is the only one solution for **passport authentication** that I have found for a week of struggles. Enjoy!

Paste code bellow in file app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate as Middleware;
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Factory as Auth;

class Authenticate extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The authentication factory instance.
     *
     * @var \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Factory
     */
    protected $auth;

    /**
     * Create a new middleware instance.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Factory  $auth
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Auth $auth)
    {
        $this->auth = $auth;
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string[]  ...$guards
     * @return mixed
     *
     * @throws \Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
    {
        $this->authenticate($guards);

        return $next($request);
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the user is logged in to any of the given guards.
     *
     * @param  array  $guards
     * @return void
     *
     * @throws \Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException
     */
    protected function authenticate(array $guards)
    {

        if (empty($guards)) {
            return $this->auth->authenticate();
        }

        foreach ($guards as $guard) {
            if ($this->auth->guard($guard)->check()) {
                return $this->auth->shouldUse($guard);
            }else{
                return null;
            }
        }

        throw new AuthenticationException('Unauthenticated.', $guards);
    }
}
```

**After this, all routes will be available for guests.**

Create new middleware DenyIfNotAuthenticated. Add there code from default app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php. It will be like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate as Middleware;

class DenyIfNotAuthenticated extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * Get the path the user should be redirected to when they are not authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return string|null
     */
    protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
            return route('login');
        }
    }
}
```

Add to Kernel.php file line: 'auth.deny' => \App\Http\Middleware\DenyIfNotAuthenticated::class, bellow 'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,

Routs in routes/api.php looks like this:

```
Route::apiResource('recipes', 'RecipesController'); // accessible for guests

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth.deny:api']], function () {
    Route::get('ingredients', 'IngredientsController@index');
}); // accessible only for authorized users
```