# Laravel passport allow API access for guest

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-passport, laravel-middleware

hello in Laravel I have implemented passport authentication and I need to allow some of my routes for unauthenticated users. I have got [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63450510/laravel-passport-allow-api-routes-for-guests-bypass-laravel-api-middleware) answer from stack overflow and but it shows the following error `Declaration of App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::authenticate(array $guards) must be compatible with Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::authenticate($request, array $guards)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Authenticate class was declaration, change your class to

```
public static function authenticate($request, array $guards)
```

not

```
public static function authenticate(array $guards)
```

> $request

is required.

Comment: No it doesnt work...

Comment: sorry try `public static function authenticate($request, array $guards)`

Comment: you're adding static only here is the error ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::authenticate(), 1 passed in /app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php on line 42 and exactly 2 expected in file /app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php on line 55

Comment: can you show `/app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php` line 42 and line 55

Comment: line 42  $this->authenticate($guards); line 55 public static function authenticate($request, array $guards)

Comment: add `$request` to line 42 `$this->authenticate($request, $guards);` and add `$request` to parent function of line 42

Comment: accepted your answer